# Ios-deploy install doesn't work - macOS High Sierra (10.13.5)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, npm

**Command line arguments** than I used for ios-deploy.

> sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm --allow-root

## Expected behavior

Install ios-deploy global via NPM

## Actual behavior.

Ios-deploy not installed and get the error 65:

/bin/sh -c /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Script-C0CD3D981F59D20100F954DB.sh
cp: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/XPCServices: No such file or directory

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Script-C0CD3D981F59D20100F954DB.sh
(1 failure)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 65
npm ERR! ios-deploy@1.9.2 preinstall: `./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 65
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ios-deploy@1.9.2 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vinicius/.npm/_logs/2018-06-20T10_50_13_426Z-debug.log

## Steps to reproduce the problem

I run the command: npm install -g ios-deploy

## System Specs

1. system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType

> System Version: macOS 10.13.5 (17F77)
>
> Kernel Version: Darwin 17.6.0
>
> Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
>
> Boot Mode: Normal
>
> Computer Name: Mac mini de Vinicius
>
> User Name: Vinicius Ribeiro (vinicius)
>
> Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
>
> System Integrity Protection: Enabled
>
> Time since boot: 36 minutes

2. ios-deploy -V

> -bash: ios-deploy: command not found
>   3. xcodebuild -version
>
> Xcode 9.4.1
>
> Build version 9F2000
>   4. xcode-select --print-path
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

5. gcc --version

> Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>
> Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
>
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0
>
> Thread model: posix
>
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

6. lldb --version

> lldb-902.0.79.7
>
> Swift-4.1

Comment: How about if you temporarily turn off SIP? I know nothing of the matter in particular, but I had to do that in order to update ruby gems.

Comment: @matt, thks! I temporarily turn off the SIP and ran the commands again. I got build sucess.

Comment: That's great! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Removed XPCServices file, and the install worked;
https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy/issues/346

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about `npm install`, but I have found that when blocked from an installation on High Sierra, such as when updating ruby gems, a simple solution is to [turn off SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261684/disable-sip-without-recovery-mode) temporarily.